# How to get count of success and failure insert while Loading data to a table in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql-loader

I am using LOAD function to load data from a file to table.
I want to know the count of success and failure insert into table.
Also what will happen once we get a failure, the load process will stop or continue with further loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suspecting you are talking about LOAD DATA INFILE. If so, this is the documentation for it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Basicly, if LOCAL is specified, all errors are treated as if IGNORE was applied, that meaning that they get transformed into warnings. If LOCAL is not specified, then errors occur upon a duplicate unique key value, but for the rest of errors, warnings are issued. If a error occurs, the rest of the file is ignored and import fails from there on.

Other errors can occur depending on the sql_mode you are operating in, regarding dta types and so on.

At the end you can get a list of warnings (errors) with SHOW WARNINGS. That should provide information about what failed and what succeeded.

Comment: Yes I meant LOAD DATA INFILE itself.Thank You.